# AWS Batch:/usr/local/bin/python: cannot execute binary file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-batch

I built an AWS Batch compute environment. I want to run a python script in jobs. 
Here is the docker file I'm using :

```
FROM python:slim
RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install boto3 matplotlib awscli
COPY runscript.py /
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

The command in my task definition is :

```
python /runscript.py
```

When I submit a job in AWS console I get this error in CloudWatch:

```
/usr/local/bin/python: /usr/local/bin/python: cannot execute binary file
```

And the job gets the status FAILED.

What is going wrong? I run the container locally and I can launch the script without any errors.

Comment: Does your python file have a shebang?

Comment: No! Is it mandatory?$

Comment: No. But if the `PATH` is not correctly set, then you may insert a shebang to inform the interpreter where to find the binary. Your local python probably has a different location than inside the container.

Comment: @samthegolden A shebang line won’t help here. In fact, since OP is calling the `python` binary explicitly, the shebang line is ignored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delete your `ENTRYPOINT` line.  But replace it with the `CMD` that says what the container is actually doing.

There are two parts to the main command that a Docker container runs, `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`; these are [combined together into one command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) when the container starts.  The command your container is running is probably something like

```
/bin/bash python /runscript.py
```

So `bash` finds a `python` in its `$PATH` (successfully), and tries to run it as a shell script (leading to that error).

You don't strictly need an `ENTRYPOINT`, and here it's causing trouble.  Conversely there's a single thing you usually want the container to do, so you should just specify it in the Dockerfile.

```
# No ENTRYPOINT
CMD ["python", "/runscript.py"]
```

Comment: I tried this solution you provided, and I got this error: `standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"`

Comment: Just a question, If I call the script in the dockerfile by CMD, then what sould I call in the command of job definition ?

Comment: [`"command"` isn't required](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_definition_parameters.html#containerProperties) and you can just leave it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with following docker file and task definition.

**Docker File**

```
FROM python:slim
RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install boto3 matplotlib awscli
COPY runscript.py /
CMD ["/bin/python"]
```

**Task Definition**

```
['/runscript.py']
```

By passing script name in task definition will give you flexibility to run any script while submitting a job. Please refer below example to submit a job and override task definition.

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session()
batch_client = session.client('batch')

response = batch_client.submit_job(
            jobName=job_name,
            jobQueue=AWS_BATCH_JOB_QUEUE,
            jobDefinition=AWS_BATCH_JOB_DEFINITION,
            containerOverrides={
                'command': [
                    '/main.py'
                ]
            }
        )
```